# Data definition has no type or storage class [type defaults in declaration]

Tags: c, linux, terminal, declaration, c99

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <curses.h>

#define EMPTY ' '
#define BORDER '*'
#define PLAYER 'P'
#define GOAL 'G'
#define COLLAPSED 'X'

typedef struct position {
    int row;
    int col;
} Position;

typedef struct node {
    Position pos;
    char collapsed_color;
    struct node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct list {
    Node* head;
    int size;
} List;

int ROW, COL;
char** map;
Position player, goal;
List history;

void initialize() {
    int i, j;

    map = (char**)malloc(ROW * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    map[i] = (char*)malloc(COL * sizeof(char));
    for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == ROW - 1 || j == 0 || j == COL - 1) {
            map[i][j] = BORDER;
        }
        else {
            map[i][j] = EMPTY;
        }
    }
}



    player = history.head->pos;
    goal = history.head->next->pos;

    map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;
    map[goal.row][goal.col] = GOAL;
}

void print_map() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            if (i == player.row && j == player.col) {
                attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
                attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
            }
            else if (i == goal.row && j == goal.col) {
                attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
                printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
                attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));
            }
            else if (map[i][j] == COLLAPSED) {
                if (i == history.head->pos.row && j == history.head->pos.col) {
                    attron(COLOR_PAIR(3));
                    printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
                    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(3));
                }
                else {
                    printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
                }
            }
            else {
                printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printw("\n");
    }
}


void collapse_floor() {
    int i, j;
    Node* new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->collapsed_color = 'r';
    do {
        new_node->pos.row = rand() % (ROW - 2) + 1;
        new_node->pos.col = rand() % (COL - 2) + 1;
    } while (map[new_node->pos.row][new_node->pos.col] != EMPTY);
    new_node->next = history.head;
    history.head = new_node;
    history.size++;

    map[new_node->pos.row][new_node->pos.col] = COLLAPSED;
}

void move_player(int row_offset, int col_offset) {
    if (map[player.row + row_offset][player.col + col_offset] == EMPTY) {
        map[player.row][player.col] = EMPTY;
        player.row += row_offset;
        player.col += col_offset;
        map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;

        collapse_floor();
    }
    else if (map[player.row + row_offset][player.col + col_offset] == GOAL){
        map[player.row][player.col] == EMPTY;
        player.row += row_offset;
        player.col += col_offset;
        map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;
        print_map();
        printf("\nYou Win!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void undo_move() {
    if (history.size > 1) {
        Node* old_node = history.head;
        history.head = history.head->next;
        history.size--;
        if (map[player.row][player.col] == COLLAPSED) {
            map[player.row][player.col] = EMPTY;
        }
        player = history.head->pos;
        if (map[player.row][player.col] == COLLAPSED) {
            map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;
        } else {
            map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;
            map[old_node->pos.row][old_node->pos.col] = COLLAPSED;
        }
        free(old_node);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    ROW = atoi(argv[1]);
    COL = atoi(argv[2]);
    player.row = atoi(argv[3]);
    player.col = atoi(argv[4]);
    goal.row = atoi(argv[5]);
    goal.col = atoi(argv[6]);
    
    history.head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    history.head->pos = player;
    history.head->collapsed_color = 'r';
    history.head->next = NULL;
    history.size = 1;
    
    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(3, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
    
    initialize();
    
    print_map();
    
    while (1) {
        int ch = getch();
        switch (ch) {
            case 'w':
                move_player(-1, 0);
                break;
            case 'a':
                move_player(0, -1);
                break;
            case 's':
                    move_player(1, 0);
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    move_player(0, 1);
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    undo_move();
                    break;
        }
        print_map();
    }
}


endwin();
for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    free(map[i]);
}

free(map);
return 0

}
```

When I try and compile the code on the terminal I get the data definition error. The error is happening at "int main" on the last 7 lines with endwin() and free(map). I tried moving them into the main function but it didn't fix the error. It's possible that I didn't implement it into the main function correctly. I realize calling it outside the function is not allowed in C99 (which is the server I use) so leaving it at the end there is not viable. The terminal says that there are type defaults to "int" in declaration of "endwin()" and "free". How do I fix this.

Comment: You can't have code outside of a function.

Comment: *"I realize calling it outside the function is not allowed in C99 (which is the server I use) so leaving it at the end there is not viable.*" ===> You already know what's wrong. What is your question, then? And C99 is not a server.

Comment: @Rasal.A What does this part of the code     player = history.head->pos;
    goal = history.head->next->pos;

    map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;
    map[goal.row][goal.col] = GOAL;
} mean?!

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    ROW = atoi(argv[1]);
    COL = atoi(argv[2]);
    player.row = atoi(argv[3]);
    player.col = atoi(argv[4]);
    goal.row = atoi(argv[5]);
    goal.col = atoi(argv[6]);
    
    history.head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    history.head->pos = player;
    history.head->collapsed_color = 'r';
    history.head->next = NULL;
    history.size = 1;
    
    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(3, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
    
    initialize();
    
    print_map();
    
    while (1) {
        int ch = getch();
        switch (ch) {
            case 'w':
                move_player(-1, 0);
                break;
            case 'a':
                move_player(0, -1);
                break;
            case 's':
                    move_player(1, 0);
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    move_player(0, 1);
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    undo_move();
                    break;
        }
        print_map();
    }


    endwin();
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        free(map[i]);
    }

    free(map);
    return 0;
}
```

this will fix the error you are talking about but there are more errors pupping up after, could you told us how to use you program so we could better help you